# Is there a way I can create a telegram bot that opens every link that comes in a channel?

Tags: telegram-bot

Is it possible to add a bot in a telegram channel that would open any link as soon as it is put in the channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can set a [webhook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook) for your bot so each time the bot recives an update (i.e. a private message, channel posts, messages from groups...) the bot will run its script. In this script you check wheter the `chat_id` of the message sent to the bot is the same `chat_id` of your channel. If so, check if the message contains a link and open it.

To search for link in a message you can use [Regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) with this expression (try [here](https://www.regextester.com/94502)):

```regex
/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/gm
```

The bot **must** be admin on your channel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but the bot will need to run all the time in the background, so you need to keep your PC always on or host the bot on the cloud

Comment: Yes I'm willing to run it in the background. Do I need to add the bot as a member of the channel ?? Would you please guide me on what all i might need to look up !! I know node a bit.  Thanks for your help